# Retries in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm writing a Lambda function which communicates with an endpoint. If a 500 error occurs, I'd like the function to retry itself several times.

I was hoping to do something like this inside my `exports.handler` function:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context){  ...
  if (!error && response.statusCode >= 500 && response.statusCode < 600) {
    if (event.retries <= 5) {
      setTimeout(exports.handler(event, context), 60000);
    }
  }...
```

> I'm wondering what the correct thing to do with the `context` variable is.

After the code I've cited above, should I `context.fail()`?  Or should I   wait for `context.succeed()` or `context.fail()` to occur in a later iteration of this retry process?

I'm just having a hard time deciding if each `context` needs to be resolved at the level of the original `exports.handler` that it appeared in, or if the `context` can be resolved and any level and that will resolve it for the whole Lambda execution.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look here:

http://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/

The function will run up to 3 times before Lambda gives up.

If you call "context.succeed", lambda will not retry, however (it assumes your function was successful).

Calling "context.fail" will cause your function to be retried.

One thing to note: you have to be careful to call "context.succeed" or "context.fail" at the right time. If you call either with pending callbacks that node hasn't processed yet, then your Lambda function will be suspended early, and some of your code may run. So, the best place to call context.succeed or context.fail is in a callback, at a point where you know that no other processing needs to happen.

It's also worth checking out this article as well:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/

Comment: Thanks for the input. We've been using something like I described above (our own retries) for some time now, but we did not test it to make sure it was behaving as hoped. If I had to depend on cloudwatch logs, it would be a bit of a slog to see if things were working right. It *seems* to be behaving correctly...

Comment: are retries depending only on context.failed or context.succeed, because I have situation that I am context.succeed in callback but my lambda still retries

Comment: Lambda may retry if any error occurs in addition to a call to context.fail. For example, if you're function times out, or throws an exception. Also, do you have any code paths in the main handler that cause it to return without calling done or succeed, or are there sequences of call backs that don't guarantee one of those?

Comment: Has this been removed? Getting this error: `AttributeError: 'LambdaContext' object has no attribute 'succeed'`. Lambda keeps trying to run my code since it's from a dynamodb stream, but I want it to just try once. (I'm using Python.)

Comment: From what I've read in the links above, Lambda only retries in certain situations, based on how you are executing the functions.  Examples of these situations include s3 bucket notifications, DynamoDB streams, and kinesis streams.  If you use API Gateway, CloudFormation Custom Resources, manually execute your functions, run them on a schedule, or some other method (which I would think are the most common use-cases?), then there is no auto-retry as far as I understand.

Comment: +1 for feature of disabling retry.

This thing is so broken. Why should it ever assume my task is retryable?

If I don't callback with error, how could I use CloudWatch to monitor error count?

Comment: `context.succeed` and `context.fail` are deprecated in Node versions greater than v0.10.42 in Lambda. You should now just use `callback(error, result)`. Source: [AWS Lambda docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-using-old-runtime.html#nodejs-prog-model-oldruntime-context-methods)